# cmake creating visual studio solution on the command line

Tags: cmake

I am using cmake 2.6.4
    WinXP Pro 
    Compiling on Visual studio 2008 VC Express edition

I can create the solution files by using the cmake-GUI. However, I don't want to use the cmake-GUI, as I always prefer the command line.

However, I am having a problem creating the solution file from the command line.

I am doing 'out of source' and this is my directory structure:

```
project/
    src/
    build/
```

I can run cmake from the build directory.

```
cmake ../src
```

However, when I try this:

```
cmake ../src --visual studio 2008
```

It doesn't work and doesn't create the solution files.

Am I doing something wrong?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you are doing it wrong.
Try invoking

```
cmake
```

to see how options are passed to it on the command line.

For your specific case, it will be:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 9 2008" ..\src
```

Answer (score 0):

When you type cmake in command line wihout any options, you will see all possible options. One of them is -G, that specifies generator for you project files.

There will be also presented a list with all possible generator names.