# CMake and editing code

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, editor

I have seen many open-source projects use CMake as their build system. I'd like to use it too, but so far all of my development has been on Visual Studio (2015). This makes me wonder how I'm supposed to edit code when using CMake as a build system? Should I use editors like Vim or emacs, or can I still use Visual Studio (with IntelliSense, if possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CMake to generate Visual Studio solution for you:
https://cognitivewaves.wordpress.com/cmake-and-visual-studio/

But unfortunately the opposite is not possible(or harder than expected), for every new file or include folder generation you will have to update your CMakeLists.txt file respectively(edits do not require updating CMake), looking at the Visual Studio flags while compiling could help this, but the process is still manual:

[Using CMake to generate Visual Studio C++ project files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395169/using-cmake-to-generate-visual-studio-c-project-files)

[cmake creating visual studio solution on the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278509/cmake-creating-visual-studio-solution-on-the-command-line)

There are also [3rd Party tools](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcproj2cmake/) which could facilitate the production cycle for you, including the visual studio to CMake generation, but they are not officially supported

Comment: Thank you, this helped! Sorry for the late reply, I approved your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `file(GLOBE_RECURSE ...)` to let CMake automatically discover all the source files inside a folder. This way, you can add and remove source files from the IDE and CMake will automatically discover them during the next run (the result will be stored in a corresponding variable).

However, this practice is **discouraged** by [the CMake Documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#filesystem) because

> then the generated build system cannot know when to ask CMake to regenerate